# Display processing orders by default in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I run a bakery ecommerce website using WordPress and Woocommerce and print the orders in the kitchen to prepare them. the confusion happens when the guys in kitchen goes on order page and they see 'All' orders together as it is the default. after explaining they weren't able to understand that they need to print orders under 'processing' tab only. I tried several snippet codes available to display 'processing' orders by default but nothing worked.

[image]